# Copying and modifying arrays in javascript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array `subAgencies` that feeds a datasource I need 2-way binding on in an Angular application. Is this the best way to copy the contents of that array to a new array, modify it and re-assign it back to the original? This works but seems too verbose.

```
this.subAgenciesOriginal = Object.assign([], this.subAgencies);
this.subAgencies = []
this.subAgenciesOriginal.splice(this.subAgenciesOriginal.findIndex(item => item.subAgencyId === subAgencyToRemove.subAgencyId), 1)
this.subAgencies = Object.assign([], this.subAgenciesOriginal);
```

Comment: It seems like you're just dropping one of the values from the copy, in which case .filter would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very readable, I would implement this with the .map method

```
this.subAgencies = this.subAgenciesOriginal
    .map((item) => item.id === subAgencyToRemove.id 
        ? newValue 
        : item
    )
```

It returns a new array, if the id is the same as the subAgencyToRemove id it replaces it somehow, if not it uses the same value. This will retain all the items in their correct index

If all you want to do is remove an item at a specific index then .filter will be a better method